# Maximize window vertically if screen edge is hit ubuntu 17.04 mate

Tags: compiz, 17.04, ubuntu-mate

I'm trying to maximize vertically a window in ubuntu mate by resizing it from the top edge. In unity, by default, this happens as the screen edge is hit. On the other hand, in mate it doesn't work.

I've been trying to fiddle with **compiz-config-settings --> window --> resize**, and I checked the appropriate box, but nothing happens.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: I feel your pain ... window managers have gotten so complex and fragile its impossible to even explain to google what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the setting at plugin **Grid** --> **Corners / Edges** --> **Top Edge**. You should set it to **Maximized**.